# Why AgilityPack not Loading From Browser dynamic text?

Tags: html-agility-pack

In scraping the following website, I am not get the table in order to scrape. I am waiting for the dynamic text to load.  But I never see the results of the correct table.

> https://masseyratings.com/nba/games

Here is my Agility Pack code:

```
var url = "https://masseyratings.com/nba/games";

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

        var doc = web.LoadFromBrowser(url, o =>
        {
            var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)o;

            // WAIT until the dynamic text is set
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("mytable0").InnerText);
        });

        int docLen = doc.Text.Length;
        currentSiteData = doc.Text.ToString();
```

I am not getting any error, I am just not seeing the table of data.  And strangely, the HTML tags are getting capitalized.

How can I get the correct data into the currentsiteData variable to further process?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by using the "PuppeteerSharp" and "AngleSharp" nuget package.
Here is my code that works.

```
using PuppeteerSharp;
using AngleSharp;

var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
        await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);
        var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = true
        });
        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        await page.GoToAsync("https://masseyratings.com/nba/games");

        var content = await page.GetContentAsync();

        var context = BrowsingContext.New(AngleSharp.Configuration.Default);
        var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(content));

        var currentSiteData = document.Source.Text.ToString();
```